# Exact Euler Maclaurin summation formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having difficulties with Euler Maclaurin summation. Lets use the next example to illustrate the issue. We pretend to calculate $S( {1 \over 2})$ as follows

$$ S\big({1 \over 2}\big) =  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{2}{\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}}$$

Obviously the value is:

$$ S\big({1 \over 2}\big) = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 1.7071067$$

My understanding is the formula -is exact- and can be written as:

${\displaystyle \sum _{i=m}^{n}f(i)=\int _{m}^{n}f(x)\,dx+{\frac {f(n)+f(m)}{2}}+\sum _{k=1}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor }{\frac {B_{2k}}{(2k)!}}(f^{(2k-1)}(n)-f^{(2k-1)}(m))+R_{p}}$

For example can as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Where

${\displaystyle R_{p}=(-1)^{p+1}\int _{m}^{n}f^{(p)}(x){P_{p}(x) \over p!}\,dx.}$

So if we apply the former expression taking $p=2$ I get:

$1.59099$.

I am using PARI/GP with the next function:

```
maclaurin(s,a,b)=  b^(1-s)/(1-s)- a^(1-s)/(1-s)+ 1/2*(b^(-s) +a^(-s) )  +  bernreal(2)/2!*( (-s)*( b^(-s-1) -  a^(-s-1) ))  +   (-1)^(2+1)* intnum(x=a,b, (-s)*(-s-1)*x^(-s-2)/2*(x^2 - x + 1/6))
```

As follows:

```
 maclaurin(0.5,1,2)=1.5909902576697319299018998147359103384
```

What I am doing wrong? Why I am not getting an exact result?

Comment: Where did that $p$ come from all of a sudden?

Comment: I believe $p$ is an arbitrary parameter. that defines the amount of derivatives you do use, am I wrong ? or it means exactly how many times the function is derivable on the interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the Wiki text, you must use the periodic Bernoulli polynomials $P_p(x)=B_p(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)=B_p(\{x\})$ not the standard polynomials in the integral for the remainder term. If you insert this in your Pari function, e.g.

`ml(s,a,b)=  b^(1-s)/(1-s)- a^(1-s)/(1-s)+ 1/2*(b^(-s) +a^(-s) )  +  bernreal(2)/2!*( (-s)*( b^(-s-1) -  a^(-s-1) ))  +   (-1)^(2+1)* intnum(x=a,b, (-s)*(-s-1)*x^(-s-2)/2*(frac(x)^2 - frac(x) + 1/6))`

you get

```
? ml(1/2,1,2)
%4 = 1.707106781186547524400844362
```

Comment: Thank you I however have two doubts more. The first one is why still not getting a more accurate result ? If the formula is an exact equality, either PARI/GP intnum does not perform a good job, or there is a missing error term o(1) on the wikipedia entrance ? This error is specially painful as soon as I add a complex heigh, for example if you try ml(1/2+33*I), even with a precision of 500 decimals, the  modulus of the error is 1.53.  You can try: abs(ml(0.5+33*I,1,2) - (1+1/2^(0.5+33*I)))

Comment: What do you mean with *why still not getting a more accurate result ?* My Pari 2.9.4 gives the error `ml(1/2,1,2)-(1+1/sqrt(2))=-5.04870979 E-29` for the standard precision and with `\p60` I get 
`7.41841230 E-68` for the difference. For your complex expression the result is  `abs(ml(0.5+33*I,1,2) - (1+1/2^(0.5+33*I))) = 1.203635967 E-66`.

Comment: You are totally right, I had a typo on my formula. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#E1), the kernel of the remainder term should be $\tilde{B}_2(x)-B_2$ where $\tilde{B}_2(x)$ is the *periodic extension* of the second Bernoulli polynomial.